# Probably defect in wording of C++ working draft (integer conversion rank rules)

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, c++20, wchar-t

I have found a possible contradiction in the [working draft of standard C++](https://eel.is/c++draft/).  First I present the facts, and my question comes at the end.

When the ***integer conversion ranks*** are established, [[conv.rank]/1.1](http://eel.is/c++draft/basic.types#conv.rank-1.1) says

> No two signed integer types [...] shall have the same integer
> conversion rank, even if they have the same representation.

[[basic.fundamental]/8](http://eel.is/c++draft/basic.types#basic.fundamental-8) says:

> Type `wchar_t` is a distinct type that has an implementation-defined
> signed or unsigned integer type as its underlying type.

Finally, [[conv.rank]/1.8](http://eel.is/c++draft/basic.types#conv.rank-1.8):

> The ranks of `char8_t`, `char16_t`, `char32_t`, and `wchar_t` shall equal the
> ranks of their underlying types ([basic.fundamental]).

In case that `wchar_t` be implemented as a ***signed integer type***, it would have the same rank as its underlying type, which is a distinct type of some other integer type.

Thus, we have two different signed integer types with identical rank, in contradiction with [conv.rank]/1.1.

Is this an actual contradiction, or I am misunderstanding when two trivially copyable types are distinct types in C++?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> we have two different signed integer types

I see nowhere in the standard that it says that `wchar_t` is a "signed integer type". Or an "unsigned integer type". I see where [it says that it is an "integer type"](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4861/basic.fundamental#11):

> Types bool, char, wchar_­t, char8_­t, char16_­t, char32_­t, and the signed and unsigned integer types are collectively called integral types. A synonym for integral type is integer type.

But the definition of "signed integer type" does not include `wchar_t`. That is, the standard clearly allows for the existence of "integer types" that are neither "signed integer types" nor "unsigned integer types".

And the statement from [conv.rank] does not apply to such types.

Comment: Hm... That's possibly still problematic. Standard does not assign (un-)signedness to any of these types – technically, though, it's just not possible that they are neither signed nor unsigned. Do we have two differing definitions of '(un-)signedness'?

Comment: @Aconcagua I have been convinced by Nicol Bolas, since it seems tht **signed integer types** and **unsigned integer types** are mere names of certain classes of integer types. The  underlying type of `char8_t` is `unsigned char`, but the classification of `char8_t` is not **unsigned integer type**, but just another integer type.

Comment: @Aconcagua: "*it's just not possible that they are neither signed nor unsigned*" Why not? If you forget the English language and just take the terms as specifically defined by the standard, then you're left with something like this: types A, B, C are X types, types D, E, F are Y types, and the types Q, R, and all X&Y types are Z types. Regardless of what words are used for X, Y and Z, if the standard does not define a *relationship* between them, then there is no relationship.

Comment: I've been considering the implementation on concrete systems. At least on the ones we have today any such type *will* be either signed or unsigned. Actually I've been satisfied with @pablo1977 's comment already, though (see his `char8_t` example) ;)

Comment: @Aconcagua 1)`char` 2)`unsigned char` 3)`signed char` can all be defined as different types. So actually I see it as a third type: *non-signedness*.

Comment: @RobertAndrzejuk `char` is always defined as a different type of `unsignec char` and `signed char`. However, `char` always behave the same as `unsigned char` or well `signed char`. All integer types (excepting `bool`) behaves the same as some underlying ***unsigned or signed integer type***. However, being classified as ***signed or unsigned integer type*** or just left it out, it is just a matter of classification.

Comment: @pablo1977 So a better name for it would be `anon-signdness` :-p

Comment: @RobertAndrzejuk I agree. Perhaps the wording in standards is not the best.