# Why `std::countl_one` doesn't work for UTF character types?

Tags: c++, c++20

C++20 added `std::countl_one`. According to [cppreference.com](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/countl_one):

> This overload participates in overload resolution only if T is an unsigned integer type (that is, `unsigned char`, `unsigned short`, `unsigned int`, `unsigned long`, `unsigned long long`, or an extended unsigned integer type).

Thus, it doesn't work for any of the UTF character types (`char8_t`, `char16_t`, `char32_t`) or `wchar_t`. That function would be useful for implementing UTF encoding/decoding. What is the exclusion for? I guess one could cast to some other integer type before calling that function, but that still seems like an unnecessary extra step.

Comment: Don't know for sure or I'd answer, but I suspect the newer character types are intended to not behave like numbers when possible, instead serving as sort of opaque data describing a character. It looks like a lot of numerics excludes them, so you don't use something that isn't *logically* an integer (even if practically speaking, it's always stored as one) in integer context unintentionally (fixing the `char` types retroactively being impossible).

Comment: @ShadowRanger they support all other types of arithmetic (add, subtract, multiply, divide, bitwise, etc). It's not like `enum class` which truly doesn't support any type of arithmetic out of the box.

Comment: Yeah, I'm not saying it makes sense to have half-assed the "is it or is it not an integer" thing, but I suspect that's the root of it.

Comment: UTF-8 is a variable-length encoding. It can not be assigned to an unique wchar_t for all of its possible unicode points.

Comment: @Ripi2 how is that relevant?

Comment: @AyxanHaqverdili it's relevant to suggested use case... none of those types represnt UTF. In fact, they are intoduced to gurantee certain size of element, nothing more. Essentially you have to work with UTF-8 and 16 as an array of char8_t

Comment: @Swift-FridayPie these types represent utf8, utf16 and utf32 encodings respectively https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/types#char16_t

Comment: @Swift-FridayPie all of these are unsigned

Comment: @Swift-FridayPie I am not sure what you mean by 'certain size' but these are also not fixed size integers. char16_t doesn't have to be exactly 16 bits.

Comment: Large enought to represent any code unit of restective encoding. But they don't represent encoding. Code units are of diffent size, tightly packed.as code unit was shorter than your actual type, devs didn't saw reason why to have separate implementation of popcount-like functions.

Comment: @Swift-FridayPie it's a function template. If it weren't for the explicit type checking in the template, it would have worked with these types.

Comment: It's at least 16 bit by definition, but alignment is same. UTF-16 code unit is exactly 16 bit. What happens if you memcpy latter into uninitialized former, and then count bits? undetermined result

Answer (score 3):

`std::countl_one` et al. are designed to work on **unsigned** types. In the proposal [P0553R4: Bit Operations](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2019/p0553r4.html) we see this small blurb that confirms it:

> For now, it is intentional that the "unsigned" requirement excludes std::byte or char, even on platforms where char is unsigned.

Given this requirement, this necessarily excludes signed char types like `char8_t`.

Comment: char8_t and all other types I mentioned are unsigned.

Comment: It is a distinct type actually. `std::byte` is as well. Unfortunately without notes from the kona meeting there's not really much else that can be expanded upon.

Comment: @AyxanHaqverdili: To clear this up, integer types can be [signed, unsigned, or neither](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66431752/734069). And while the underlying type of character types may be unsigned, the character types *themselves* are never considered unsigned.

Comment: @NicolBolas That is interesting. If I overflow a `wchar_t`, is that undefined behavior or not? `std::is_unsigned` seems to think it is unsigned. I am not arguing though. I will simply add the appropriate cast. Thank you for the explanation.

Comment: @AyxanHaqverdili: It works because `is_unsigned` is explicitly defined by how `T(0)` and `T(-1)` compare to one another (if `T` is an integral type).